# Selecting XML Value from field with xml string in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am trying to change to get a value from an xml string.  This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT * FROM bench_request WHERE bench_request.start_date >= 'Mar 11 2022  8:59AM'
```

In my table I have a field called recurrenceinfo that contains an XML string.  Here is an example of that field:

```
<RecurrenceInfo 
Start="03/08/2022 08:00:00" 
End="03/21/2022 08:00:00" 
WeekDays="62" 
Id="c46571d7-220f-4e75-ad7c-843e8868d63f" 
Range="1" 
FirstDayOfWeek="0" 
Version="2"/>
```

What I am trying to do is get the start date from the xml string to use in replace of bench_request.start_date.  So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM bench_request WHERE "Start from XML string" >= 'Mar 11 2022  8:59AM'
```

Basically I am trying to get all rows where the recurrenceinfo(Start) >= 'Mar 11 2022  8:59AM'.

I have searched and searched and can't figure it out.  I have tried:

```
SELECT  recurrenceinfo.query(N'/RecurrenceInfo/Start') AS [Start] FROM bench_request
```

But I get an error "Cannot find either column "recurrenceinfo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "recurrenceinfo.value", or the name is ambiguous."

How can I accomplish this?  recurrenceinfo field is of type string, not xml.  Also get the attribute start

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your query doesn't give me that error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5523335f3d9759220deadf6e14826ef). That suggests that the column *isn't* called `recurrenceinfo`. Also you want the `value` method, not `query`. `Start` is also an attribute of `RecurrenceInfo` *not* an element.

Comment: @Larnu, fyi, the field recurrenceinfo in the table is of type string.  I tried value as well but get same error.

Comment: You can't use `xml` methods on a string based data type, @dk96m . You'll need to `CONVERT` the data first; or better yet fix the design and store your XML data as `xml`.

Comment: ok, so i change the table so that field is of xml type.  @Larnu

Comment: So now that I changed it to XML, I am a bit closer.  I tried SELECT 
recurrenceinfo.value('(/RecurrenceInfo//Start/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as StartDt
FROM bench_request but all i get back are null values.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, the key was changing the datatable field from varchar to XML, then the following worked:

```
SELECT recurrenceinfo.value('(/RecurrenceInfo/@Start)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as StartDt FROM bench_request
```

Comment: You can change the data type to `datetime` although it doesn't help that the format is not an unambiguous one (depends on language/region)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is important to use ISO 8601 standard for DATE AND TIME formats
[ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)

Unfortunately, your XML values are not compliant with the standard.
That's why there is some @Start attribute value massaging to make it ISO 8601 compliant.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @benchrequest TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, recurrenceinfo XML);
INSERT INTO @benchrequest (recurrenceinfo) VALUES 
('<RecurrenceInfo Start="03/08/2022 08:00:00" End="03/21/2022 08:00:00" WeekDays="62" Id="c46571d7-220f-4e75-ad7c-843e8868d63f" Range="1" FirstDayOfWeek="0" Version="2"/>'),
('<RecurrenceInfo Start="05/25/2022 08:00:00" End="03/21/2022 08:00:00" WeekDays="62" Id="c46571d7-220f-4e75-ad7c-843e8868d63f" Range="1" FirstDayOfWeek="0" Version="2"/>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @var DATETIME = '2022-03-11T08:59:00';

SELECT *
FROM @benchrequest
WHERE recurrenceinfo.exist('/RecurrenceInfo[xs:dateTime(concat(substring(@Start,7,4),"-",
substring(@Start,1,2),"-",
substring(@Start,4,2),"T", substring(@Start,12,8))) ge xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@var"))]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

select SUBSTRING(recurrenceinfo,25,19) from bench_request

This will give you the "Start" as String. Then you must convert it to datetime field